# RSpec Fail the rspec file

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have two rspec files in my spec/ folder and when I call rspec it runs both of them. Each file has two rspec conditions(it). I'm raising an error at the first file at first condition(it), and the result is, first and second condition run in both of those examples.

Here's what I need, when first condition fail at first example, it should stop the first file conditions. But the second file should work without problem. I've tried to use fail_fast but when I use it, the second file is also not running.

Here's my first file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "A" do
  it "first condition" do
    willgiveanerror #raise error
    puts "A says hello"
  end

  it "second condition" do
    puts "Will write this"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sth like:

```
before(:each) do
  fail if @failed
end

after(:each) do
  @failed = true unless example.exception.nil?
end
```

Comment: try with @@ instead of @